# Dropbox /delta ignoring cursor

Tags: python, json, dropbox, python-requests, dropbox-api

I'm trying to list files on [Dropbox for Business](https://www.dropbox.com/developers/business/docs).

The [Dropbox Python SDK](https://www.dropbox.com/developers/core/sdks/python) does not support Dropbox for Business so I'm using the [Python requests module](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/latest/) to send POST requests to https://api.dropbox.com/1/delta directly.

In the following function there are repeated calls to Dropbox /delta, each of which should get a list of files along with a cursor.

The new cursor is then sent with the next request to get the next list of files.

BUT it always get the same list. It is as though Dropbox is ignoring the cursor that I am sending.

How can I get Dropbox to recognise the cursor?

```
def get_paths(headers, paths, member_id, response=None):
    """Add eligible file paths to the list of paths.

    paths is a Queue of files to download later
    member_id is the Dropbox member id
    response is an example response payload for unit testing
    """

    headers['X-Dropbox-Perform-As-Team-Member'] = member_id
    url = 'https://api.dropbox.com/1/delta'
    has_more = True
    post_data = {}

    while has_more:
        # If ready-made response is not supplied, poll Dropbox
        if response is None:
            logging.debug('Requesting delta with {}'.format(post_data))
            r = requests.post(url, headers=headers, json=post_data)
            # Raise an exception if status is not OK
            r.raise_for_status()

            response = r.json()

            # Set cursor in the POST data for the next request
            # FIXME: fix cursor setting
            post_data['cursor'] = response['cursor']

        # Iterate items for possible adding to file list [removed from example]

        # Stop looping if no more items are available
        has_more = response['has_more']

        # Clear the response
        response = None
```

The full code is at https://github.com/blokeley/dfb/blob/master/dfb.py

My code seems very similar to the [official Dropbox blog example](https://blogs.dropbox.com/developers/2013/12/efficiently-enumerating-dropbox-with-delta/), except that they use the SDK which I can't because I'm on Dropbox for Business and have to send additional headers.

Any help would be *greatly* appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you're sending a JSON-encoded body instead of a form-encoded body.

I think just change `json` to `data` in this line:

```
r = requests.post(url, headers=headers, data=post_data)
```

**EDIT** Here's some complete working code:

```
import requests

access_token = '<REDACTED>'
member_id = '<REDACTED>'

has_more = True
params = {}
while has_more:
    response = requests.post('https://api.dropbox.com/1/delta', data=params, headers={
        'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + access_token,
        'X-Dropbox-Perform-As-Team-Member': member_id
    }).json()

    for entry in response['entries']:
        print entry[0]

    has_more = response['has_more']
    params['cursor'] = response['cursor']
```

Comment: If I do that I get a `Bad Request` response. I tried using `data=post_data` and setting the header `Content-Type: 'application/json'` manually but Dropbox still seemed to ignore the cursor.

Comment: I'm sure it is something to do with encoding that cursor, but can't fathom what. Please let me know if you have any insights! To be honest, I don't understand the difference between JSON encoding and form encoding.

Comment: `application/json` is definitely wrong... the API is expecting form encoding, not JSON. What was the body of the 400 response?

Comment: If I use `data=post_data` I get `requests.exceptions.HTTPError: 400 Client Error: Bad Request`

Comment: Yes, but what's the actual body of the response? i.e. `r.content`?

Comment: `r.content` is `b'{"error": "Bad HTTP \\"Content-Type\\" header: \\"\\".  Expecting one of \\"application/json\\", \\"application/json; charset=utf-8\\"."}'`

Comment: Are you sure you changed the right line? The one that's calling `/delta`?

Comment: I added some working code to my answer in case that helps.

Comment: I think you've nailed it... the call to https://api.dropbox.com/1/team/members/list seems to need JSON encoding but the call to https://api.dropbox.com/1/delta seems to need form encoding. I'll do some more testing and mark your answer correct if it works. Thanks.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/80483/discussion-between-blokeley-and-smarx).